# Xml output in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want table output as XML. My table result is

[image]

I need result like

[image]

Query

```
Declare @colorTable table (Category varchar(100),Attribute varchar(100))
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Red')
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Blue')
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Green')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Bus')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Car')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Twoweeler')

select * from @colorTable
FOR XML PAth(''), ROOT ('xml'), ELEMENTS;
```

Thanks,

S.Sundar

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? For example, using `select ... for xml`.

Comment: Yes I tried. not getting result like what i expected

Comment: If you will show some of your attempts then someone could point to the errors you've made. Otherwise it looks like "please write code for me" request.

Comment: I tried like this `Declare @colorTable table (Category varchar(100),Attribute varchar(100))
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Red')
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Blue')
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Green')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Bus')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Car')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Twoweeler')
 
select * from @colorTable
FOR XML PAth(''), ROOT ('xml'), ELEMENTS; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to write a query using `GROUP BY`, XML path not allowed to write sql within `xml path(not allowed select statement)`

```
Declare @colorTable table (Category varchar(100),Attribute varchar(100))
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Red')
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Blue')
insert into @colorTable values ('Color','Green')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Bus')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Car')
insert into @colorTable values ('Transport','Twoweeler')

select T1.Category as '@Value',
       (
       select T2.Attribute as '@Value'
       from @colorTable as T2
       where T2.Category = T1.Category
       group by T2.Attribute
       for xml path('Attribute'), type
       )
from @colorTable as T1
group by Category
for xml path('Category'), root('xml')
```

OUTPUT

```
<xml>
  <Category Value="Color">
    <Attribute Value="Blue" />
    <Attribute Value="Green" />
    <Attribute Value="Red" />
  </Category>
  <Category Value="Transport">
    <Attribute Value="Bus" />
    <Attribute Value="Car" />
    <Attribute Value="Twoweeler" />
  </Category>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your particular case to achieve your goal you should made three subselects for your three subbranches `Color`, `Transport` and `Electronics` and then join that xml parts under `xml` root.

You can do it using following query:

```
select
    (
        select
            Attribute as 'attribute/@value'
        from @colorTable
        where Category = 'Color'
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as Color,
    (
        select
            Attribute as 'attribute/@value'
        from @colorTable
        where Category = 'Transports'
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as Transports,
    (
        select
            Attribute as 'attribute/@value'
        from @colorTable
        where Category = 'Electronics'
        for xml path(''), type
    ) as Electronics
for xml path(''), root('xml')
```

Comment: color , transport will come dynamically. that is not static

Comment: @user2354274 Having dynamic element names in your xml looks like a bad idea. So if it should be dynamic, consider changing your xml structure from `<Color>...</Color>` to `<Category name="Color">...</Category>`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `EXPLICIT Mode with FOR XML` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx). It can be a pain , but you can control the output ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I put code like this

> Select Category as value ,
>   (SELECT   Attribute as value  from @colorTable where Category= a.Category
>         FOR XML raw('attribute'), 
>       TYPE) 
>   from @colorTable as a     group by Category 
>   FOR XML raw('category'), ROOT ('xml'), type;